# How to put a ribbon image on another image with css?

Tags: css, image, overlay, ribbon

I would like to show a ribbon for some pictures on my project. Below the main image, I need to show a description. This is what I have right now:

```
<img src="images/img1" alt="" style="width:150px; height:150px"/>
<br />
<img src="images/ribbon.png" style="position:relative; top:-151px; left:49px" />
<br />
Description
```

Now, take a look at the images below:
[image]
What I need is the right one, but what I have now is the left one. The space between image and text must be remove. I also remove last `<br />` but the problem  did not solve.
Please help me to solve it.
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4AXdy/

Comment: Create a jsFiddle of your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4AXdy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4AXdy/4/)**

**The Code Change:**

```
<img src="http://www.aroose-shahkar.com/images/ribbon.png" style="
left: 155px;
margin-left: -73px;
margin-top: -99px;
position: relative;
top: -99px;" />
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: May you tell me the roll of margin-top and margin-left here?

Comment: Its is like an effect to overcome the effect of existing attributes or those attributes that have not been declared at the time of resetting the stylesheet. - @MohammadBagherSaberi

Comment: Ideally, this should have been achieved using background image and not image. - @MohammadBagherSaberi